# Autofilling form values in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, autofill, unique-values

In a PHP web page, when flling the form and some of the fields are filled incorrectly, I need to return to the same page and auto-fill all the fields that were prefiously filled by the user. How do I set the values of the fields?

I tried using the $_POST method and echo but the error was that the key I used was undefined.

Comment: **One of the common methods** :- use session variables

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` will show you what keys are defined. For text use `if (isset($_POST['name']) echo $_POST['name'];` to fill value conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, if you do use `echo` then make sure you escape the output, ie

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
```

otherwise you risk injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

You can store values ​​in an array called data$
And if there is an error, return this array to the page and use the value method to fill in the pre-filled values.
Example

```
    $data =[
 'name' => $_POST['name']
 ];
 if(empty($data['name']){
 $data['name_err']= "error name";
 }
```

And on the desired page:

```
 <input value="<?php echo $data['name'] >?">
 <span><?php echo $data['name_err'] <span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can use a session to store the form values.

    <?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();
    
    // Store values in session//
    $_SESSION['form'] = ['first_name' => isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '', 'last_name' => isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '', ];
    ?>


<input name="first_name" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['form']['first_name']) ? htmlspecialcharc($_SESSION['form']['first_name']) : ''; ?>">
<input name="last_name" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['form']['last_name']) ? htmlspecialcharc($_SESSION['form']['last_name']) : '' ?>">
```